# Can't get my navbar to align properly in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is what the navbar looks like at the moment.[image: The layout with navbar]
But I want to align it across the whole horizontal side of the page.
I've tried changing the sidebar column to 1 / 3 but it didn't work sadly.

```
    background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.95);
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    
}
```

Here's the codepen link so it's easier to see what's up: https://codepen.io/arkzy/pen/ZEVmyJr

Comment: Can you expand more on `align it across the whole horizontal side of the page`?

Comment: Surround the navbar block ( <div class="navbar">  ) with another div and center that.

Comment: You have a grid with five areas.  You can try defining css for grid template which will allow the nav bar to occupy the entire horizontal area: `grid-template-areas: 
    'navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar'
    'sidebar topcard topcard topcard topcard topcard'
    'sidebar bottomcard1 bottomcard1 bottomcard1 bottomcard2 bottomcard2'`. Each area can be a div within the grid container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `grid-row: 1 / 3;` from `.sidebar`.
Add `grid-column: 1 / 3;` to `.navbar`.